# How to get a string when writing a perl hash into a yaml ('1_1' => will be 1_1: in yaml format)

Tags: python, string, perl, integer, yaml

I have a perl script which writes a hash into a file using YAML::DumpFile. The perl hash contains keys like '11':  and '1_1':. When I look into the yaml file I see that there is no string anymore, it is 11: and 1_1: (valid yaml syntax as far as I know). The problem is when I read this file with the as non string marked keys with python I loose one entry, because both 11: and 1_1: are handled as 11:.

In the past I tried different proposal I found in the web but none of them solve my problem.

This code generates the my.yaml file

```perl
use Data::Dumper;  
use YAML;
my %hash = (
           '11'  => { 'TEST' => 'my_test_1' },
           '1_1' => { 'TEST' => 'my_test_2' }
           );

print Dumper \%hash;

YAML::DumpFile( "my.yaml",\%hash );
```

this code uses the my.yaml file

```py
import yaml

def my_construct_mapping(self, node, deep=False):
    data = self.construct_mapping_org(node, deep)
    return {(str(key) if isinstance(key, int) else key): data[key] for key in data}

yaml.SafeLoader.construct_mapping_org = yaml.SafeLoader.construct_mapping
yaml.SafeLoader.construct_mapping = my_construct_mapping

data = yaml.safe_load(open('my.yaml').read())
print(data)
```

The files and printouts are:

perl print.Dumper

```perl
$VAR1 = {
          '1_1' => {
                     'TEST' => 'my_test_2'
                   },
          '11' => {
                    'TEST' => 'my_test_1'
                  }
        };
```

so '1_1' looks for me lika a string.

The my.yaml looks like:

```
---
11:
  TEST: my_test_1
1_1:
  TEST: my_test_2
```

I expect that I see a '1_1': in the my.yaml file but I get 1_1: which result in the removal of the '11' entry.

Comment: Haven't tried, but possibly... [`local $YAML::QuoteNumericStrings = 1`](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML#QuoteNumericStrings)?

Comment: @Amadan I think that would not quote `1_1` since it is not numeric.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I haven't tested whether `YAML` module considers it to be numeric (it should), but `1_1` is numeric in Perl (equivalent to `11`), just like in Ruby. Try: `perl -e "print 1_1;"`

Comment: Your Perl library is doing the wrong thing. https://yaml.org/type/int.html clearly states *Any “_” characters in the number are ignored, allowing a readable representation of large values.* The flip side of that is that any string consisting of numerals and underscores, needs to be quoted in YAML. And unquoted `1_1` in YAML is the same key as `11`

Comment: Library might be wrong in terms of YAML but in Perl can have integers in the form of `$var = 1_000_000` to represent a more readable million. Edit: also, what about https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::Tiny instead

Comment: The relevant code in the Perl [`YAML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML) module is [here](https://metacpan.org/source/TINITA/YAML-1.29/lib/YAML/Dumper.pm#L497). You can see that it uses [`Scalar::Util::looks_like_number()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util#looks_like_number) and quotes if `$YAML::QuoteNumericStrings == 1`

Comment: I suggest you add an issue at [yaml-pm](https://github.com/ingydotnet/yaml-pm/issues)

Comment: Since nobody here has said they actually _tested_ setting `QuoteNumericStrings` yet, I just tried adding it to the code in the question. Using YAML 1.29 (the current version as of this comment), it quoted `'11'`, but did _not_ quote `1_1`.